# onactiveindex tab control changed event not firing in ajax update panel

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

This is a asp.net / c# question.

I have a tab control that has two tabs, I have an event handler that runs on the "onactiveindexchanged" event that does some validation.  The tab container is set to autopostback="true".  This works fine, until I put the tab container in an ajax update panel.  Now when I change tabs the onactiveindexchanged event no longer fires?

So my question is should the onactiveindexchanged event still work in an update panel?

Cheers
Alex

Comment: After spending hours on this yesterday for some reason this is working as expected today.

Answer (score 0):

After removing and adding the update panel again, this is working as expected.  Must have been some syntax issue.